# Table rate shipping with multiple shipping methods pulling rate from USPS

Tags: checkout, shipping

So I'm trying to setup table rate shipping. My client wants to present the customer only one shipping option based on their location. As an example: for x number of items and USPS zones 1-4, they want to calculate shipping based on weight/destination. However, for zones 5-8, they want to charge a flat rate. I've tried the Matrix Rates extension, but it seems to require that I put in the rates, when in reality, I need it to ask USPS for the rates based on the correct shipping method.

I have also tried Webshopapps Zone Table Rate extension, but I can't get support from them beyond "refactor the extension because it's old and it may not work." The whole idea behind using an extension is to not have to write the module myself.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Are you still looking for an extension?

Answer (score 2):

Kris, feel free to reach out to me personally to discuss this, I can't find you on my emails.

In this scenario you can achieve what you need but you would need another extension to be able mix the live rates with custom rates as the USPS zones extn only does custom rates. If you email us and put FAO Karen I'll reply further.

To implement this yourself is not a small task, because it sounds like you are wanting to override rates and also doing a zone lookup via the USPS api.  Obviously do-able but a fair bit of coding required.

Comment: Fair answer, Karen!